How do I get y-axis ticks in vega-lite to be "nice" round numbers evenly spaced?
I'm using vega-lite in deneb for the first time. I've created a line with multi y-axis. On the right side y-axis, Vega is automatically assigning the data point exact values as the tick labels and intervals (see attached image). For example, for the % axis I want it to be 20%, 25%,30%... I want the ticks to be round numbers with even interval spacing between the ticks. Similar to how the left side y-axis is done. I've tried "tickCount" which doesn't work. I've pasted my code below too. Could it be a data type issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!
3 Axis Chart
I tried allowing vega to automatically assign the tick and intervals because I expected the default was to use round numbers. What happened was vega used the data table's exact values for the tick and intervals.
 `{
      "data": {"name": "dataset"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "PERIOD_YEAR",
          "type": "nominal"
          }
   },
    "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line"
      },
      "encoding": {
          "y":{
            "field": "QTY",
            "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
   {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y":{
          "field": "GM%_Less LC__formatted",
          "sort":"-y"
          }
        }
      },
    {
    "mark": {
    "type": "line"
    },
    "encoding": {
    "y": {
    "field": "GM $/unit_Less LC__formatted",
    "sort":"-y",
    "axis": {"offset":80}
      }
    }
    }
    ],
    "resolve": {"scale": {"y":"independent"}}
    }`



Can  you share a .pbix? Upload to an external site and share a link.

@davidebacci I'd love to but that would violate company policy. Do you have any educated guesses? Maybe this is something, when I include "quantitative" as the type for either "GM%Less_LC--formatted" or "GM $/unit_Less LC__formatted" the line and axis ticks go away. But when I use "nominal" the lines appear. My measures are formatted as whole numbers or percentage. Could something with my formatting still be off? If this is impossible without the .pbix file I understand. I appreciate you even reading this!

Just create some dummy data which reproduces the problem. It is very hard to debug this type of stuff without seeing the full picture.

@davidebacci Thank you! The attached dummy data recreates the issue.  [link] (https://github.com/jt8215/Projects/blob/main/Dummy%20Data.pbix )

@davidebacci Thank you! It's now working. Adding the scale zero false make it work for some reason. I still have to leave out type quantitative because that makes my axis values disappear. So leaving that out but including the scale works! Weird I guess. I really appreciate all the time you put in. This is great!!

If you set the type to quantitative, you get nice tick values. You can set the domain extents to whatever you want. I'm confused as I thought you'd tried this? Is this the result you're looking for?

{
  "data": {
    "name": "dataset"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Year"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Quantity",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "GM %",
          "sort": "-y", "type": "quantitative", "scale":{"zero":false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "GM $ / Unit",
          "sort": "-y", "type": "quantitative","scale":{"zero":false},
          "axis": {
            "offset": 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "scale": {
      "y": "independent"
    }
  }
}

